# Azure Landing Zone Bicep Accelerator - Explain values for the .env file

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

When using the ALZ Bicep Accelerator, the following step is required when using ADO Pipelines...

> "4. Create your ALZ Bicep Accelerator framework with the following ALZ PowerShell Module cmdlet:
> New-ALZEnvironment -o <output_directory> -cicd "azuredevops"

> ***Various prompts will be displayed which will be used to replace parameter values as well as to create an environment variables file (.env) that will be used by the Azure DevOps pipelines.***"

I understand that the **New-ALZEnvironment** cmdlet will generate the ALZ code to then push to ADO, but my question is, what exactly are these values referring to? The code generator spits out the values you provide for each prompt in this .env file, but what exactly is it asking for? I have put questions marks where I am unsure, below. I do not see this explained in any of the (otherwise excellent) documentation.

TOP_LEVEL_MG_PREFIX="alz"

LOCATION="eastus"

**IDENTITY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="???"**

**CONNECTIVITY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="???"**

**MANAGEMENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="???"**

UPSTREAM_RELEASE_VERSION="v0.16.3"

CONNECTIVITY_RESOURCE_GROUP="rg-alz-connectivity"

LOGGING_RESOURCE_GROUP="rg-alz-logging"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Connectivity Subscription - if you need hybrid connectivity between azure and on-premises

Identity Subscription - if you need to setup azure vms as domain controllers

Management Subscription - this is usually used to consolidate billing and cost management

EDIT: It's explained in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/landing-zone/design-areas

Comment: Hello Thiago. I have seen the Subscriptions in the ALZ hierarchy. I should have been clear that I am asking specifically in regard to https://github.com/Azure/ALZ-Bicep/wiki . The documentation here does not seem to state anywhere that these Subscriptions should be manually created beforehand, and are only referenced when you run the New-ALZEnvironment cmdlet, which prompts for the ID's of these Subscriptions.

Comment: My understanding would be, as well, that ALZ-Bicep excepts those subscriptions to be manually created before running the accelerator. And no, I don't think this is explicitly mentioned anywhere in the documentation in that repository.